# ng-focus, ng-blur doesn't works on input type checkbox on safari

Tags: html, angularjs, safari

ng-focus, ng-blur doesn't works on input type checkbox,radio on safari
Here is the sample code: https://jsbin.com/ladeba/2/edit?html,console,output

Comment: BTW the safari version that am using currently is 9.1.1 version